# How to locking window server 2008 dont use shortcurt key?

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

I want to only use mouse to lock window server 2008 when i using remote desktop and dont want to disconnect because im copying file from server. How can I do this ?

Comment: From the start menu?

Comment: Click the "x" in the top right corner...remote into same session 3 hours later to verify copy job complete...profit?

Comment: No, im using remote destop to mapping driver from my PC to server

Answer (score 2):

Run the following:

```
rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation
```

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315249.aspx)

Comment: Feel free to upvote it and accept it as an answer.